# Javascript fire function from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, svg, path

I would like to add a path on an `svg`, from an "object".
`myPath()` for the attribute `d` works fine, but
I want to trigger my function from the object `obj`, and the `obj.action()` for `d` doesn't work... Why ?

```js
var obj = {
  action: function() {
    myPath();
  }
}

function myPath() {
  return "M 10 10 L 50 10 L 50 90 L 10 90 Z";
}

$("button").on('click', function() {
  // doesn't work... :-(
  $("svg").find("path").attr("d", obj.action());

  // ... but it's working with this :
  //$("svg").find("path").attr("d", myPath());
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button>
<svg><path /></svg>
```

Comment: You action returns nothing... `action: function() { return myPath() }`

Comment: `object = { action: myPath }` might be simpler?

Comment: Or `action: () => myPath()`

Comment: @epascarello ...Your solution works like a charm ! It was just a question of syntax ... I spent hours searching everywhere on Google and tried lots of possibilities with parentheses, brackets, curly brace etc... :-)
Many Thanks !

Comment: @evolutionxbox... same thing...:-) Many Thanks

Comment: @Barmar... same thing... :-) Many Thanks

Comment: @epascarello Go ahead and create an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :

```
var obj = {
  action : function() { return myPath() }
  // action : myPath //other solution
  // action : () => myPath() //other solution
}

function myPath() {
  return "M 10 10 L 50 10 L 50 90 L 10 90 Z";
}

$("button").on('click', function() {
  $("svg").find("path").attr("d", obj.action());
});
```